# Fill DataTable asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following function in a .NET Core 2.0 app.

```
public DataTable CallDb(string connStr, string sql)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connStr);
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

How to convert it to an async function?

```
public async Task<DataTable> CallDb(string connStr, string sql)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connStr);
    da.Fill(dt); // No FillAsync to await?
    return dt;
}
```

I need to use `DataTable` because the sql may return data with different schema. Any better way to handle the dynamical schema?

Comment: Wondering why did you tag this with [tag:entity-framework-core]?

Comment: It's a .Net core app which uses EF core 2.0

Comment: I don't see it used at all in this question, making it irrelevant. But how are you planning to use this method? You can do this with EF Core depending on the complexity of what you want

Comment: This code is fundamentally flawed. It will force you to use horribly insecure method for building your sql strings that leave your programs crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You need an additional parameter defined for the method that allows it to accept SqlParameter data.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, security is not an issue in my case of the particular project.

Comment: First, it's about more than just security. Parameters also help avoid naive data problems, like people named `O'Brien`, and they help improve performance. Second, this is the exact attitude that leads to bad code in other projects when it does matter. Parameters are just the right way to do it. Learn to use them properly and account for them in your common data patterns, so when code that was just for fun suddenly becomes real you're already doing things the right way.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I had to use dynamical sql in the project and security is not an issue in the particular project. `'` has been addressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the initial call to `ExecuteReaderAsync()` will not block in this case, `dt.Load(reader)` probably does the equivalent of `reader.Read()` rather than `await reader.ReadAsync()`, and may block the calling thread while retrieving rows.

If you do need a `DataTable` for use with an external API, or because you don't know the field definitions in advance, but require fully asynchronous behaviour, you might be better off to use your own code to construct a `DataTable`, add the required columns e.g. based on `reader.GetName()` and `reader.GetFieldType()`, and then populate it with rows in a loop using `await reader.ReadAsync()` and `dt.Rows.Add()`.

Answer (score 33):

`SqlDataAdapter` was never updated to include the TPL version of the methods. You could do this:

```
await Task.Run(() => da.Fill(dt));
```

But that would be creating a thread that would do nothing useful.

A good approach would be to use something like this:

```
public async Task<DataTable> CallDb(string connStr, string sql)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    var reader = await connection.CreateCommand().ExecuteReaderAsync();
    dt.Load(reader);

    return dt;
}
```

Of course, some changes like `using` statements should be made. However, here you are using asynchronous calls the right way.

Comment: Although this answer gets around the issue by using another await in the method, it isn't freeing up the thread when the bulk of the IO happens in dt.Load. That's where the big benefit of using async lies.

Comment: @SaebAmini - but surely it is freeing up the thread while SQL Server is processing the query and before it starts returning the results?   So there is some gain, and it could be quite significant.

Comment: @Joe true, there is some gain as you're freeing up the thread for the round-trip time + the time SQL server takes to actually process the query. That portion _could_ be significant if you have high latency/a complex query that takes a lot of time to process. But I wanted to point out that the majority of IO usually happens when you're actually retrieving the results from the reader, which is still being performed synchronously in `dt.Load`. To get that benefit, you should use the async methods provided by `SqlDataReader`: `NextResultAsync` and `ReadAsync`, or create your own `dt.LoadAsync`.

Comment: There is an issue on github for adding Async functionality to the DataAdapters API.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22109

Answer (score 3):

Building off [Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49078619/591285) answer I wanted to asynchronously handle loading the data table from the async reader (`DataTable.Load`).

I created a `SqlCommand` extension which reads the data in one record at a time. Although the data is still loaded synchronously the data is at least iterated asynchronously one record at a time using `ReadAsync`.

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static async Task<DataTable> FillDataTableAsync(this SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {

            DataTable schemaTable = await reader.GetSchemaTableAsync();
            dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                dt.Columns.Add(row.Field<string>("ColumnName"), row.Field<Type>("DataType"));


            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Add();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    dr[col.ColumnName] = reader[col.ColumnName];
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

and use it like so;

```
DataTable dt = null;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", conn))
{
    dt = await cmd.FillDataTableAsync();
}
```

If I need to asynchronously update the `DataTable` I delete the records then use `SqlBulkCopy` `WriteToServerAsync(dt)` inside a transaction;

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE", transaction.Connection))
{
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

}
using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(transaction.Connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
{
    copy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE";
    await copy.WriteToServerAsync(dt);
}
```

**Note: I have not tested this for efficiency vs `SqlDataAdapter`.**

Comment: Four times slower than SqlDataAdapter? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c83e9ef-c663-43d5-a737-18b7a19f4534/get-datatable-async-huge-performance-issue?forum=aspwebapi

Comment: @TreeAndLeaf I suspected that could be the case :( Although I'm a little suspicious of this test. It calls `await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` on every read and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You could speed it up by not copying the metadata if it wasn't needed. Some like this (untested!):
`DataTable dt = new();
using (var reader = await sqlComm.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
  while (await reader.ReadAsync())
  {
    var values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
    reader.GetValues(values);
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
  }                  }
                    return dt;`

Comment: Perhaps dt.BeginLoadData() and dt.EndLoadData() would help with performance