# C# Interacting with Database In async way, not working.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I just wanted to create a dummy ASP.NET MVC project where i wanted to explore more about async & await.I created async methods in DB access Layer and Repository Layer and i also make sure that the action is also written in async way. I noticed that a single method takes around 7ms to execute, so logically if i call the method 3 times i also should take 7 ms or around 7ms ! But its taking about 20-23 ms. I am sure that i am doing something terribly wrong. My Code snippet goes below:

**DATA ACCESS LAYER:**

```
    public async Task<DataTable> DtGetAllCustomers()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _dtCustomer = new DataTable();
            _connectionString = Repo.GetConnString();
            _spName = "spGetCus";
            _spParameters = new SqlParameter[]
            {
            new SqlParameter("@QryOption",1)
            };
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = _spName;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(_spParameters);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(_dtCustomer);
                        conn.Close();
                        da.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        return _dtCustomer;
    }
```

**REPOSITORY:**

```
 public async Task<List<CustomerModel>> GetAllCustomers()
            {
                _dtCustomer = await _customerDal.DtGetAllCustomers();
                List<CustomerModel> allCustomers = new List<CustomerModel>();
                return allCustomers = (from DataRow row in _dtCustomer.Rows
                                       select new CustomerModel
                                       {
                                           CustomerId = (int)row["CustomerId"],
                                           CustomerName = (string)row["CustomerName"]
                                       }).ToList();
            }
```

**ACTION:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            List<CustomerModel> model = new List<CustomerModel>();
            CustomerRepo2 aa = new CustomerRepo2();
            await aa.GetAllCustomers();
            await aa.GetAllCustomers();
            await aa.GetAllCustomers();
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            ViewBag.time = elapsedMs;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think that calling 3 methods with `await` will execute them in parallel? Parallel programming and asynchronous programming are different concepts. You should get familiar with the theory before writing code

Comment: Besides that, wrapping a method with `Task.Run` is considered a bad practice. Moreover, creating Thread Pool threads to do I/O operations is a waste of processing power. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078458/fill-datatable-asynchronously/49078619#49078619) to see how you can do that query in a truly asynchronous way

Comment: As a last comment, you may want to look into an ORM instead of loading a DataTable to then get your entities

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know the basic difference ! neither i am expecting "Parallel" performance nor exactly 7 ms ! Please read my question carefully, i mentioned "should take 7 ms or around 7ms" ... so it may 10 or 13 or any near value . is it logical to take 3 times of single execution ! thats why the question raised in my mind :)

Comment: In my mind, 7x3 = 21, not 10 nor 13. 20-23 seems about right

Comment: https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/   what about this article ? Please have a look on "Waiting on Multiple Calls" section .

Comment: That's because of the Task.Delay being an asynchronous operation. As I mentioned in my second comment, you are wrapping synchronous operations in a Task, which is a waste.

Comment: Thanks Camilo ... now i get the point here. i have been studying for few hours what you mentioned in previous comments. My logic behind using Task.Run is i am just assigning another thread to do the work and not keeping current thread busy. and as i mentioned its just a dummy project, so every time Task.Run will not gonna do such tiny work ! sometimes i need to read a large excel file, process it and then upload data to db table, in such case i think i can use a thread from thread pool just to speed up the whole process. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Not really. Creating a thread is just for making the application generally more responsive, it won't make it faster. Every I/O operation (reading from/to disk, databases, network requests) should be done with framework async methods. You should only use `Task.Run` to perform calculations or other in-memory complex processing

Comment: If you want I can post a more complete answer later today

Comment: that will be very appreciated :)  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're awaiting each call, so before it can move onto the next, it will pause execution. Consider creating three tasks, and awaiting them all with [`Task.WhenAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var task1 = aa.GetAllCustomers();
var task2 = aa.GetAllCustomers();
var task2 = aa.GetAllCustomers();
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```