# Task<DataTable> does not contain definition for 'Rows'

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code that get data from database

```
public async Task<DataTable> SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
        if (param != null)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        await Task.Run(()=> da.Fill(dt));
        return dt;
    }
```

and I use this code to run stored procedure

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetOrderManagementManagerEmail()
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt =await DAL.SelectData("GetOrderManagementManagerEmail", null);
        DAL.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

then I use this code on a click of button

```
private async void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] selectedRows = gridView2.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow rowGridView2 = (gridView2.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;
          await  stock.ValidateProjectNeed(Convert.ToInt32(rowGridView2["id"]), DateTime.Now);
        }
        if (XtraMessageBox.Show(Resources.addedSuccessfullyBonBesoinAndSendEmail, Resources.Validate, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {


            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;

            oMsg.To =await Task.Run(()=> stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail().Rows[0][0].ToString());
            oMsg.Subject = "Bon Besoin " ;
            oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            oMsg.Display(false); //In order to display it in modal inspector change the argument to true
            oMsg.HTMLBody = "Un nouveau bon besoin a été ajouté " +
                "<br />" +  oMsg.HTMLBody; //Here comes your body;

        }
        gridControl2.DataSource = stock.GetProjectNeedsForValidate();
    }
```

but I get error in this line of code

```
oMsg.To =await Task.Run(()=> stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail().Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Task does not contain definition for 'Rows' and no accessible extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?).
before I use async the code work fine.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail()` is probably an async method that returns `Task<DataTable>` which is not a DataTable, you need to either async the anonymous Method, done like so: `async () => ...` or use the Result like so `stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail().Result.Rows...` keep in mind that using the Result Property is a blocking call

Comment: Why *don't* you use `await`? In any case, `GetOrderManagementManagerEmail()` returns a Task. The DataTable is stored in the `Result` property of the task. `Task.Result` is a blocking call though. Use a simple `var table = await stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail()` instead

Comment: I'd strongly suggest revisiting the data access here. You have a combination of what appears to be a shared connection object and exiting data access methods whilst the connection is till in use by other tasks. Share connection *strings*, not connection objects and if possible, use the built-in `XxxAsync` methods rather than using `Task.Run`. There is a place for `Task.Run`. This isn't it.

Comment: @MindSwipe "The stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail() is probably an async method" actually it is exactly that. It is posted in the question

Comment: E.g. [Fill DataTable asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078458/fill-datatable-asynchronously)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want:

```
var table = await stock.GetOrderManagementManagerEmail();
oMsg.To = table.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Not sure what's happening with the `await Task.Run()`. You are getting a `Task` back from the call to to `GetOrderManagementManagerEmail()` and then attempting to retrieve rows from a task, wrapped in a....

Simplify it. Also, take a look at whether you really need to use tables/rows with indexers. You can use:

```
var oMsg.To = table.AsEnumerable().Select(d => d.Field<string>("To")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: An explanation as why the error arose in the first place and why your solution solves it would really boost the quality of your answer, and it would justify the upvote that I just gave you ;)

Comment: @MongZhu yeah, I agree, and I was writing one :-) but trying to be objective.

Comment: @MongZhu :-D I meant, not sure why it was written that way. My work is full of misfired humour.

Comment: :D ok got it, but my comment is wrong. I just tried it. actually the compiler is smart enough to infer the return type / generic parameter of `Run<T>` and it does the job actually, but it is still twice as async as necessary

Comment: I appreciate your participation and help me solve my problem, thank you very much.