# Task/await to fill DataTable - no performance improvement

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, async-await, task

This is my first time trying to learn how to use Task/await, and I admit I am struggling.  It does not seem to let go of my user interface any faster than before I used it.

Am I using it correctly?  I know I do not truly understand Task/await, so a modified version of my own code would be excellent if you can.

Here is how I call my task method:

```
DataTable dt = await datalayer.GetDocumentInfo (InvestigationID);
```

Here is my code that fills my DataTable:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDocumentInfo (Guid InvestigationID) {

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (new Impersonator.Impersonator (UserLogin, UserDomain, UserPassword)) {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection (ConnectionString)) {

            // Specify which stored procedure to use and add a parameter.
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("GetDocumentInfo", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@InvestigationID", InvestigationID);

            // Put the returned record into a datatable.
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //dt.Load (dr);
            await Task.Run(() => dt.Load (dr));
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }   // Impersonator

    return dt;

}
```

Comment: I believe you are not awaiting all the expensive calls, for example, cn.open. Why not try refactoring the body of the function to a new function and in this function's body becomes await task.run(newFunction). The new function would return the datatable without any reference to task

Comment: You probably wanted to say *responsiveness* instead of *performance*.

Comment: I meant "perceived performance."  Didn't think anyone would latch onto that term.

Comment: The *async and await pattern*, is a *scalability* feature that allows you to write scalable code in a succinct and elegant manner. If that is your idea of performance, you win.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect a performance improvement you are barking totally the wrong tree. Async/await is a mechanism to save threads, NOT a mechanism to make things faster, particularly if the time they spend on anything is dependent ON AN EXTERNAL SYSTEM.

Example: Ordering Pizza (ordering, by telephone)

- Sync: You tell your friend to order it and wait until he is finished, standing besides him.
- Async: You tell your friend to order it and he comes back and tells you he ordered it.

Both operations will take the same time, but in the async case you can go on watching TV while your friend does the phone call, while in the sync case you have to stand besides him making the call.

The async case likely takes longer (you need to wait for your friend to get back), but you can do something else in the meantime.

And while we do code review:

> SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
> //dt.Load (dr);
> await Task.Run(() => dt.Load (dr));

This is as bad as it gets. THis is literally telling your OTHER friend to wait and observe your first friend doing the call then report back to you - NOTHING gained, except wasting another persons time.

nothing against await, but the correct way to use it it TO USE IT. Directly. And here your datatable gets bad: Datatable is old and has no proper support for async.

[Fill DataTable asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078458/fill-datatable-asynchronously) has an in depth explanation about why this is not sensible at all.

You will find that most people do NOT use datatables. AT ALL - EntityFramework et al work a LOT better and faster in 99.999% of the cases.

You could, though, at least replace this:

> SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

with

> var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

See, this one has an async method. Same with the connection open.

Comment: Thanks.  i hesitated on using the word "performance", but I thought people would get the gist of what I meant, which is "perceived performance."  I will give the async cmd a shot.  Appreciate the help.