# Updating a DataTables contents in an async method doesn't refresh bound DataGridView properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, datagridview

I got three `DataViews` in my Program, where each has a `DataTable` connected that I full and update (via merge and deleting some rows) from an `SqlAdapter`. Updating is done in async Methods, where needed wrapped in my own `Task.Run(...)` Actions. After the updates the `DataGridViews` don't show the updated data although the combination of `DataGridView`, `DataView` and `DataTable` normally takes care of that.

This seems to break the automatic refresh of the `DataGridViews` that are bound to the `DataViews`. Observing the `DataBindingComplete` events of the `DataGridViews` reveals, that it is not properly fired when I update my underlying `DataTables` in async methods. When updating all three `DataTables` I only observe the event being fired for one of the `DataGridViews` at a state during the update process, where there is only one row in the `DataTable`... after the async method finishes the update there are far more rows that never get shown. My `DataGridViews` show the proper updated data as soon as I change the sorting of a column.

In the button's event that triggers the refresh I did another test:

```
private async void AddSomethingToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender is ToolStripButton button) {
        int test1 = DataGridView1.RowCount; // 4
        int test2 = ((DataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource as DataView).Count; // 4

        /* Calls async method to write new value to DB and calls more async methods to refresh
         * all the DataTables with the new data which also effects the one in this example */
        await controller.AddSomethingToSqlDbAndRefreshDataTableAsync();

        int test3 = DataGridView1.RowCount; // Still 4
        int test4 = ((DataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource as DataView).Count; // 5
    }
}
```

Those values are never in sync as they should be. After trying to manually refreshes by calling `Refresh` on the `DataGridView` or `ReadValues` on the `Binding` I managed to get it working by calling `ResetBindings` on the `BindingSource` which doesn't really feel right.

Is there something I am missing? Shouldn't I be using those data structures and mechanics in combination with the `async/await` pattern?

Edit - Example for a refresh method:

```
private async Task RefreshDataViewAsync(string query, DataView view) {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        using var con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        using var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        var newtable = new DataTable();
        adapter.FillSchema(newtable, SchemaType.Source);

        foreach (DataColumn col in newtable.Columns) {
            if (ColumnValueTypeMapping.TryGetValue(col.ColumnName, out Type coltype)) {
                col.DataType = coltype;
            }
        }

        adapter.Fill(newtable);

        view.Table.Merge(newtable, false);

        /* Remove rows that are not present anymore */
        var rows2del = new List<DataRow>();
        string[] primarykeys = view.Table.PrimaryKey.Select(keycol => keycol.ColumnName).ToArray();
        foreach (DataRow row in view.Table.Rows) {
            if (!newtable.Rows.Contains(primarykeys.Select(key => row.Field<object>(key)).ToArray())) {
                rows2del.Add(row);
            }
        }
        rows2del.ForEach(row => row.Delete());

        view.Table.AcceptChanges();
    });
}
```

Comment: If you need to access the BindingSource, store it as a Field object and use it directly. -- Where are the *wrapped in my own Task.Run(...) Actions* parts? If you use async methods, what's `Task.Run()` for? Are you resetting the bound DataTable? If you do, the bindings are lost.

Comment: I only accessed the binding sources like this for my tests, if using them in the future is the solution I choose I will make it prettier :D
I added an example for a refresh method where I never Clear/Delete either the DataView nor the DataTable attached to it.
Task.Run is used because there are no versions of the SqlAdapter methods that are async. The binding is still working as it shows when I change the sorting of a column.

Comment: The DGV doesn't automatically get repainted after datatable gets updated.  Trick is to set to null.  DataGridView1.DataSource = null; DataGridView1.DataSource = newtable;

Comment: Task.Run() executes in ThreadPool Threads. You have `SqlConnection.OpenAsync()`, `SqlCommand.ExcuteReadAsync()` that you can `await` and then `[DataTable].Load([IDataReader])`, so you can remove `Task.Run()`. -- Not sure what that Merge plus DataRow tampering is for. Shouldn't you use the Merge method overload that specifies how to handle the PrimaryKey while merging two tables with the same schema? Pass the DataTable instead of the DataView to then access it as a DataTable. The update notifications must reach the BindingSource, otherwise it doesn't know.

Comment: @Jimi those are ways to go about removing teh Task.Run() I didn't know about. I can look into that but I can't imagine that changes the problem. The row tempering is to remove rows in the local copy that are not present in the remote on anymore. Surely I could pass the table instead of the view, but the chain for the changed-event would still have to be DataGridView->Binding->DataView->DataTable, wouldn't it?

Comment: I described the way to remove `Task.Run()`: all data access method provide an async alternative, as described. You can `await` those methods, so you don't need to run that code in a Thread other than the UI Thread (what `Task.Run()` does). Using `async/await`, there are no Threads involved. DataBinding doesn't work the same cross-Thread. -- As also mentioned, that's no really the way to update a DataTable, you should fix that part of the code, too.

Comment: @Jimi This approach still makes a long blocking call to `[DataTable].Load([IDataReader])` which has no async variant. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078458/fill-datatable-asynchronously. That's why I haven't tried it yet. Not sure whether that blocking call would be noticable in my scenario, will have to try that now that you said "cross thread binding" can be problematic. About the updating, I haven't found a better aproach which removes rows from the local table, excluding approches where I would have to write my own DataTable extension or similar... but that's off-topic I guess.

Comment: If you have an `async` method that `awaits` async method calls (as, e.g., `await SqlConnection.OpenAsync()` etc.), it doesn't matter whether this one: `[DataTable].Load([IDataReader]`; see also the overloads of this method) has no async version, you're not accessing any UI Element here. Your method is awaited in the UI Thread anyway. So, keep your `private async Task RefreshDataViewAsync()`, but await those async methods calls there. You could also change the return Type in `Task<DataTable>`.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of async/await to unblock the UI message loop to not freez the UI while waiting for long (here) IO-calls?! And the Load method would be such a call, just as conneting and getting the reader, no? Using the non async version would cause my UI thread to jump back into the method to do the load in a blocking manner after `OpenAsync()` and `ExcuteReadAsync()` has been awaited. At that point it would be a design question. Block and leave with the UI potentially frozen during `Load` or have a thread just awaiting the IO-calls but not freeze the UI and then refresh manually.

Comment: Your `async` method, since it awaits (real) `async` method calls, is executed asynchronously. You can await it and it's not blocking. In an async method, you can have code that doesn't use async calls. There's no need. Assume you load data using async I/O calls, then you need to sort the data, using an array or whatever: that part of the code is not asynchronous, but your method is executed asynchronously anyway. Different story if you try to access UI elements in that async method... (don't, or learn how to `BeginInvoke()` safely).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231426/discussion-between-thomasw-and-jimi).

Comment: Then, it depends on the context of the operations and on what methods you're using. E.g., you cannot do: `var result await DoSomethingUnrelatedAsync();` then, e.g., `var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));`, but you can do: `var result await DoSomethingUnrelatedAsync(); var files = await Task.Run(() => Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));`. If you find that, in that context, a blocking method cannot be made async, `Task.Run()` it. The results of this call, however, are returned in your (non-threaded) async method.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your UI code from your non-UI code.

```
private async void AddSomethingToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1.DataSource = await GetDataAsync();
}
```

Your `GetDataAsync` method may use `Task.Run`. In fact, given that it's Windows Forms, it, probably, should.

Comment: That is the exact pattern I implemented. If the methods private protection level confused you, it is called by another public method of my Controller/ViewModel that in turn is called by the async event handler from my Views Code Behind.
Anyway, that is no solution for my problem where the update event doesn't reach the DataGridView.

Comment: I don't see on your code where the `DataSource` is being set. You can't rely on databinding from another thread.

Comment: I don't do the binding in another thread, I do it right in the Loaded event of the Form. Initially the data is displayed properly, so the binding works. After a refresh it is erroneous but as soon as I change the order/sorting of a column via UI the new values are properly displayed again, so the binding is working there too.

Comment: *given that it's Windows Forms, it, probably, should*: care to explain this statement (in the answer)?

Comment: To get away from the UI thread as soon and for as long as possible.

Comment: Changing the data source in another thread may not rebind,

Comment: Causing an update in a non-UI thread is likely the source of your problem. Try doing something like calling Rebind using Form.Invoke

Comment: @Flydog57 that is exactly what I am doing atm as said in the inital post, but I wanted to know if there is a "better", automatic way