# Make this method asynchronous correctly

Tags: c#

I have this method that opens the connection to sqlserver, I need it to be asynchronous, so far everything is correct, but I see that it asks to wait  "await"

```
public async static Task<DataTable> ToList(string nombreProcedimiento, List<Parameter>? parametros = null)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new(conn);
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new(nombreProcedimiento, conexion)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            if (parametros != null)
            {
                foreach (var parametro in parametros)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametro.Name, parametro.Value);
                }
            }
            DataTable tabla = new();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd);
            da.Fill(tabla);
            return tabla;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null!;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
```

I see that I am missing something like that

```
 return await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

but i can't put it because i'm not executing a query but a stored procedure

```
CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

How can I create this async method correctly?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078458/fill-datatable-asynchronously

Comment: Also, you should [avoid using `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Lots of things are dubious with your code, starting with the choice of using `DataTable`, which is a memory hog for larger result sets, but also not using `using` to dispose resources, and silently throwing away exceptions. Asynchronous execution is not the first thing you should be worried about. Consider replacing this kind of "helper" boilerplate with Dapper.

Comment: Hi, adding `async` to your method does **NOT** make your code asynchronous. It does not start a new thread. `async` only indicates to the .NET runtime that you have `await` statements in your method. It is in fact these **calls** that may be (or possibly not, who can tell) running code on another thread. `await` indicates that the execution pointer on the current stack frame should not continue until a signal from the spawned thread is received.

Comment: `Fill` doesn't support `async`. You'll need to either fill the DT manually or wrap the `Fill` call in  a `Task.Run`. (I'm assuming this is a UI app).

Answer (score 1):

I see in your code that you've created a SqlCommand object but never executed it.
Your query Type isn't important, to execute any type of query and make your method asynchronous you have to call one of these methods provided in the SqlCommand object and await it.

- ExecuteScalarAsync
- ExecuteReaderAsync
- ExecuteNonQueryAsync

Comment: `da.Fill` will execute (sync) db queries.