# How to create an asynchronous method with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, ado.net

How can I create this synchronous to asynchronous method?

```
 public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query)
 {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     try
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
             {
                 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                 dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
             }
         }
         return dt;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new Exception("Error al ejecutar consulta: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

Modify synchronous code to asynchronous

Comment: DataTable... honestly, just isn't in vogue; DataTable is not the recommended way of working with data and hasn't been in a very long time, and accordingly: they haven't received much love, and no FillAsync or LoadAsync methods have been added. Do you actually need DataTable? Working with proper typed data (via tools like Dapper or EF) is *absurdly* easy these days, making working with DataTable very unusual

Comment: Could you edit the question and clarify what you mean with *"modify synchronous code to asynchronous"*? 1. Change the return type to `Task<DataTable>`. 2. Don't block the current thread. 3. Don't block any thread. If you are unsure what you mean, please read this article first: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: At least DataAdapter isn't written for that so you would need to roll your own thing with a DataReader to get usable async methods to not just fake asnychronous code. But calling that stuff from ADO.Net yesterdays technology would be an understatement. If you don't need to don't do that anymore.

Comment: @Ralf to be clear: ADO.NET is still extremely relevant: it is just DataTable, DataSet, DataAdapter etc that are ... "less relevant" (picks words carefully)

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure. I meant that with "that stuff from ADO.Net" and not everything in ADO.Net.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill DataTable asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078458/fill-datatable-asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the SqlDataAdapter class is synchronous. You could probablly do something like bellow.

```
await Task.Run(() => dataAdapter.Fill(dt));
```

So the final results could look like.

```
public async Task<DataTable> ExecuteQuery(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync(); // Open the connection asynchronously

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => dataAdapter.Fill(dt));
                }
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error al ejecutar consulta: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

That being said I would recommend using a more modern technique with actual async support.

This is not techniqualy asyncronous Task.run is running it on another thread to avoid blocking.

Comment: That doesn't make it truly asynchronous, though - it must moves the blocking to a different thread. That *might* still be useful, but: it isn't true async

Comment: @MarcGravell I wish we had available some better terminology than "fake async" vs "true async". :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Migrate from DataTable to typed objects, usually POCOs, then
2. Use Dapper or EF or similar, any of which support true async

Step 1 is the big one, obviously - lots of code changes